# Browser extension to zap images with keyboard shortcut

Tags: browser-addons, productivity, bookmarklet

I'd like to find a browser extension or bookmarklet (Chrome and/or FF) that allows me to zap all images on a page with a single keystroke (CTRL+number for example)

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [zap images](https://www.squarefree.com/bookmarklets/zap.html) bookmarklet works for actually zapping the images.  In Chrome you can run it by searching for the name of the bookmarklet or using [SiteLauncher](http://www.donesmart.com/sitelauncher/) (it works in both Firefox and Chrome) and would let you run it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>+letter.